# Trigger acts weird when updating rows

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a `trigger` that updates a `row` at once. but I'm having some weird problems in doing updates.
When I try to put a more bigger value in `commission_pct`, the trigger shows another error and not the error that I put into it.

```
    end if; --The errors are in the next sentences
ELSIF   UPDATING ('COMMISSION_PCT') THEN
    if (:NEW.commission_pct <> 0 and (:OLD.job_id <> 'SA_REP') or (:OLD.job_id <> 'SA_MAN')) then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'You cannot have commission'); 
    end if; -- When testing, SQL Developer says here is an error
```

When testing the updating `commission_pct` part, it shows me `error -20002` when trying to raise the `commission_pct` to an `SA_REP` or a `SA_MAN` Also, when updating `commission_pct` of an employee who isn't a `SA_REP` or a `SA_MAN`, it updates and the trigger does not stop it . 
What should I do? I have a syntax error? I am using `SQL Developer`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a problem with conditional operators (AND has higher precedence then OR)

```
if (:NEW.commission_pct <> 0 and (:OLD.job_id <> 'SA_REP') or (:OLD.job_id <> 'SA_MAN')) then
```

Maybe you wanted this:

```
if :NEW.commission_pct <> 0 and :OLD.job_id <> 'SA_REP' and :OLD.job_id <> 'SA_MAN' then
```

Or

```
if :NEW.commission_pct <> 0 and :OLD.job_id not in ('SA_REP', 'SA_MAN') then
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the problem. And yes, it was that I wanted.